# Slow first connect through nginx

Tags: nginx

I have issue with nginx as below:
my website have peak request is 30000req/sec and max traffic to nginx server ~300Mbps, Nginx is proxy http server.
Sometime users connect to some server in my system through nginx, The first connection is verys slow (>10s) to connect to server, then connect to server the next connections is very fast (<1s)
The nginx configuration as below:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
error_log  /storage/log/vn-fw/nginx/log/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  10240;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  15;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush  on;

    client_body_buffer_size     1k;
    client_header_buffer_size   4k;
    client_max_body_size          5M;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    proxy_buffers 8 16k;
    server_tokens off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
}
```

and version kernel:

> Linux vn-nginx2 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 11 19:39:25 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And kernel version

> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
>
> net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
>
> net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
>
> kernel.sysrq = 0
>
> kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
>
> net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
>
> kernel.msgmnb = 65536
>
> kernel.msgmax = 65536
>
> kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
>
> kernel.shmall = 4294967296
>
> net.ipv4.ip_conntrack_max = 393216
>
> net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
>
> net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
>
> net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 86400
>
> net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0

Please help me troubleshoot this issue.
Thank you very much

Comment: TCP Slow start? What is the kernel version?

Comment: Kernel version: Linux vn-nginx2 2.6.18-348.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 11 19:39:25 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. and kernel config:   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

kernel.sysrq = 0

kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

kernel.msgmnb = 65536

kernel.msgmax = 65536

kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

kernel.shmall = 4294967296

net.ipv4.ip_conntrack_max = 393216

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 86400

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I'm updating to cent6.7 .and check again

Comment: Have you been able to upgrade to CentOS 6.7?

Comment: Thanks Antony, I updated to Cent 6.7, The issuse still appear. I think the root cause from my iptables rule.

Comment: @PhongĐặng Was you able to resolve the issue. Actually I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to kernel version you have RHEL5 which comes with out-of-dated TCP/IP configuration stack and TCP initial congestion window set as 2/3.

You tried to disable it via net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0 which causes unexpected behavior and doesn't help with performance. Turn it on before continue. Rather than this, please pay an attention to values of **tcp_wmem** and **tcp_rmem**.

Let's see through [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) what TCP congestion window is and how it works

> Slow-start is part of the congestion control strategy used by TCP, the
>   data transmission protocol used by many Internet applications.
>   Slow-start is used in conjunction with other algorithms to avoid
>   sending more data than the network is capable of transmitting, that
>   is, to avoid causing network congestion. The algorithm is specified by
>   RFC 5681.
>
> Slow-start begins initially with a congestion window Size (cwnd) of 1,
>   2 or 10.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuIdf.png) The value of the Congestion Window will be increased with
>   each acknowledgment received, effectively doubling the window size
>   each round trip time...

If we would try to image this with [a diagram](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/13/velocity-tcp-and-the-lower-bound-of-web-performance/):

[image]

In terms of bytes send over we can display it like that:

[image]

Based on Kernel version you have the value of TCP congestion window is 2/3 which was increased up to 10 by default in RHEL 6.2

> In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2, the TCP initial congestion window
>   default is now set to 10, according to RFC 5681. Additionally, the
>   initial-window code common to TCP and CCID-2 has been consolidated.

So the question is still open, what to do? The answer is easy: upgrade your kernel (recommended) or to adjust the window value:

```
ip route change default via `ip route| awk '/^def/{print $3}'` dev eth1 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10
```

Be careful to set the interface correctly, it can be eth0 or different. After system reboot the value is reset, so make sure you have it setup on boot via rc.local. Before do be aware of potential problems with kernel 2.6.* https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6021

Don't also forget that window resizes down in certain interval of time controlled by **net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle** value.

```
echo "
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096  87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096  87380 16777216
" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```